# SQLcombine continuous records

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008, plsql

I have a database table that is used to version in/out results based on the user "version". I need to combine where the Source and Target match, and where there is a Activate record that comes directly after a Deactivate record.

What I have currently:

```
ID     Source   Target  Activate    Deactivate
361440  1760     2569    1          78
532741  1760     2569    79         80
532742  1760     2569    81         84
574687  1760     2569    95         97
574687  1760     2569    98         NULL
```

What I would like to have:

```
ID     Source   Target  Activate    Deactivate
361440  1760     2569    1          84
574687  1760     2569    95         NULL
```

EDIT: My example only included a continuous chain of 1 additional record, there are some cases where the chain exists for multiple records. There is also the case where the Deactivation version has not been set yet. I have updated my example to reflect this.
Thanks

Comment: Does the table contain lots of data?

Comment: Yes, the table contains around 125,000 records. But, this query will only be ran once, as opposed to part of an application. The amount of time it takes to run is not much of a concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for the data sample you provided:

```
SELECT 
  v1.ID, 
  v1.source, 
  v1.target, 
  v1.activate, 
  COALESCE(v2.Deactivate, v1.Deactivate) as Deactivate  
FROM Versions v1 LEFT JOIN 
   Versions v2 ON v1.source = v2.source
              and v1.target = v2. target 
              and v1.Deactivate + 1 = v2.Activate
```

But you need to decide what you want to do if you have a continuous chain of several records.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! In my example, I failed to mention that some of the continuous records are in a series more than a single chain. There are also cases where the Deactivation version has not been set yet, making it active indefinitely. I have updated my example to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Are PL/SQL functions acceptable? This adds some boilerplate as I needed to create two additional types, but once this is done, this is only a question of looping through a `CURSOR`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE merge_items_rec AS OBJECT (
  ID NUMBER(6),
  SOURCE NUMBER(6),
  TARGET NUMBER(6),
  ACTIVATE NUMBER(4),
  DEACTIVATE NUMBER(4)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE merge_items_tbl AS TABLE OF  merge_items_rec;
```

Here I used a [`PIPELINED`  function](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=207) in order to handle properly very large data set. I don't know is this was necessary in your case. But I feel like it was a clean way of doing things:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION merge_items
RETURN merge_items_tbl PIPELINED
AS
  -- assuming your data table is called MYTABLE
  CURSOR data IS SELECT * FROM MYTABLE ORDER BY SOURCE,TARGET,ACTIVATE;
  acc  MYTABLE%ROWTYPE;
  curr MYTABLE%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  OPEN data;
  FETCH data INTO acc;

  IF data%FOUND THEN
  LOOP
    FETCH data INTO curr;

    -- emit a row when there is not more row to fetch,
    -- OR if the newly fetched row does not coalesce with the one stored in `acc`
    IF data%NOTFOUND OR acc.source != curr.source 
                     OR acc.target != curr.target 
                     OR acc.deactivate + 1 != curr.activate THEN
      PIPE ROW(merge_items_rec(acc.id, acc.source,acc.target,acc.activate,acc.deactivate));
      EXIT WHEN data%NOTFOUND;
      acc := curr;   
    ELSE
      acc.deactivate := curr.deactivate;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  END IF;

  CLOSE data;
END;
```

Usage:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(merge_items())
```

Producing:

```
ID      SOURCE  TARGET  ACTIVATE    DEACTIVATE
361440  1760    2569    1           84
574687  1760    2569    95          -
```

Answer (score 0):

A totally different approach might use Oracle [`CONNECT BY` hierarchical queries](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm). The idea here is to build a path from "consecutive" rows (according to activate/deactivate):

```
SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT A.id AS ROOTID,
       A.SOURCE,
       A.TARGET, 
       CONNECT_BY_ROOT A.activate AS ACTIVATE, 
       A.DEACTIVATE
    FROM MYTABLE A 

    --    Keep only path ending on a leaf node (i.e.: no following range)
    WHERE CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF <> 0

    --    Make a path by chaining consecutive rows
    CONNECT BY PRIOR A.deactivate+1 = A.activate
           AND PRIOR A.source = source
           AND PRIOR A.target = target

    --    Keep only path starting on a root node (i.e.: no previous range)
    START WITH NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MYTABLE B WHERE B.deactivate+1 = A.activate)
```

Producing:

```
ROOTID  SOURCE  TARGET  ACTIVATE    DEACTIVATE
361440  1760    2569    1           84
574687  1760    2569    95          -
```